# Android GtalkService port 5228 blocked but Market worked

Tags: android, iptables, google-talk

I blocked with iptables output destination Port 5228, that seems to be used from GTalkService. I wanted just to block them and it works. I see into the GTalk Service Monitor and the Connecting status is false. So that Gtalk Talk Service is blocked the Market and other Google things must not to worked. But it works! I can download apps from Market. This is very strange to me. I read various pages about GTalkService and in all of them stands, that if GtalkService is blocked, the Market can´t working too.
I have blocked it with:

`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT`

Can somebody help me please, and explain why Google Market works?

Answer (score 0):

Change ACCEPT to REJECT if you want to block outgoing connections to port 443